# How to create an instance of a type defined in a Web Site Project (App_Code) from another library

Tags: c#, asp.net, activator

I'm trying to create an instance of type defined in a `Web Site Project`. The type name is configurable, so therefor known, but for the assembly name is not possible to tell the name at the configuration moment, since the Web Site Project is compiled by ASP .Net.

```
var typeName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["typeName"];
var assemblyName = '.. get the assembly name ..';

var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(assemblyName, typeName);
return (IUserCredentials)instance.Unwrap();
```

Is any easy way to use this `CreateInstance` overload  or shall I search through all loaded types and find it by name?

This code is used in another library, which is referenced in the Web Site Project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`App_Code` is the name assigned to the assembly that contains types residing in the App_Code directory types, so you should:

```
string assemblyName = "App_Code";
```

Comment: @TimBooker, that's simply the name the compiler assigns, no black magic.

Answer (score 1):

How about getting the assembly off of a type that you DO know exists in the web application, and using that:

```
typeof(MyWellKnownType).Assembly
```

Comment: the class is not known, only the interface, the interface follows to be implemented by a consumer of that library and now it happens the consumer to be a Web Site Project

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the exact answer but, if you have the code of the class you need, you can add it to your other project as a link and directly use it instead of employing reflection.

Comment: The idea is to have an implementation of that interface outside that project.